# Node js in not saving data in MySql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I have the following code. When i execute it, i get

Database connected successfully! 1 record inserted. But it saves no data in MySql database.
Im pretty sure my code is correct, but do someone has any tip or advice?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var dbconn = mysql.createConnection({
   host: "localhost",
   user: "root",
   password: "",
   database: "assessment"
});
dbconn.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("Database connected successfully!");

  var sqlquery = "INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ('john', 'jmpleom')";
  dbconn.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.affectedRows + " record inserted");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried committing the data to the database? As a failsafe from unfinished queries, databases will rollback any records to their original state if the data is not committed to the database.

After your insert query, try it out. Based on your code it might look something like this:

```
  dbconn.commit(function(err) {
        if (err) { 
          connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
```

Comment: If there's no transaction, mysql will autocommit every statement

Comment: @evert By default yes - though from the description of the OP it sounds like they have [`autocommit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) set to off.

Comment: what MySQL client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To save or commit data you have to end the connection like this:

```
dbconn.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Database connected successfully!");

var sqlquery = "INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES('john','jmpleom')";
dbconn.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.affectedRows + " record inserted");
    dbconn.end(); //like this
});
```